# Can I load different variables from the same .less or .css files for different clients?

Tags: css, colors, less

I want to have one .less file (and, subsequently, one .css file) for several clients; all clients are using same pages with same elemetnts and layout.

The problem is, all clients have different colour schemes, so is there a function in less that allows to use one set of rules for one client and a different set of rules for another, but from the SAME file?

Without changing classes/IDs of the elements, or using several folders and files for each client. Also, please, no javascript and/or jquery, just pure LESS/CSS

Example:

```
/*client1*/
.element {color:white}

/*client2*/
.element{color:black}
```

Comment: make colors as variable and use that variables to color different elements.
For Example 
`@white: #ffffff;`
/*client1*/
`.element {color:@white}`
/*client2*/
you have to only change the variable.
`@white: #000000;`
your code will not change
`.element {color:@white}`

Comment: that's easy, but how can I make the file "understand" which client it is? I want one color for client 1 and a different color for client 2 to be loaded from the SAME stylesheet; what is the equivalent of if/else statement for .less (if there is one)?

Comment: Why not assign a different `id` to the parent tag for each client and then decide on color schemes based on the `id`?